# Identification of two components

Tags: identification, components

Can you help me identify these two components? I cannot find information on them on the web. They appear to be ceramic filters of some kind.

Front of Component 1:
[image: Front of Component 1]

Back of Component 1:
[image: Back of Component 1]

Front of Component 2:
[image: Front of Component 2]

Back of Component 2:
[image: Back of Component 2]

Comment: They look like tantalum capacitors.

Comment: They are probably resettable fuses

Comment: these cannot be filters, because they'd need a third/ground pin to dump rejected energy into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are resettable fuses, the big one is 600V for 160mA

https://www.distrelec.nl/en/radial-resettable-fuse-240-ma-ohm-littelfuse-trf250-120/p/16026991

The second is 30V for 1.6A

https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/resettable_ptcs/littelfuse_ptc_30r_datasheet.pdf.pdf